# Why override is not working?

Tags: html, css

I have a `footer` and I set all margin and padding to be zero at the start. When I want to set my footer to `text-align: center` , nothing changed for`my .footer p`. 
However the padding is still 0 horizontally, not 9px vertically.

```
 .footer{
        background-image: url("../img/naviga.png");
        width: 1000px;
        height: 30px;
 /* my div settings */
        background-repeat: repeat-y;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: center;
 /* my div settings */
        font-family: verdana, arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 10px;
      }

 /* p tag is my footer text */
.footer p{
         padding: 9px auto 9px auto;
         }

[have a look plz][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/D77IT.png   */
```

Why this override is not working? I also tried with `!important`.

Comment: use padding: 9px auto 9px auto !important; , "!important" property for must @Chao LI

Comment: `auto` is an invalid property for `padding`.

Comment: You've cut the selectors out of the image. A live page would be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do `padding: 9px auto` because `auto` is an invalid property for `padding`. That's why property is lined-through in the picture you provided.

Check the MDN docs for `padding`, [**here**](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_padding.asp).

> All the padding properties can have the following values:
>
> `length` - specifies a padding in px, pt, cm, etc.
>
> `%` - specifies a padding in % of the width of the containing element
>
> `inherit` - specifies that the padding should be inherited from the parent element

---

Here's one of a few ways to vertically and horizontally align your text in the middle. Check this [**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/wt78mes1/1/) or the snippet below.

```css
  .footer {
    display: table;
    background: red;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 30px;
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: verdana, arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
  }
  .footer p {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
```

```html
<div class="footer">
  <p>
    text
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: So, based on your correct text answer, why do you provide invalid code with `padding: auto`?

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone, thanks for pointing that out. I forgot to remove it when copying the code from the OP.

Answer (score 1):

You can`t use auto at padding. 
Try it for css :

`.footer p {
    padding: 9px 0px;
  }`

and don't miss your footer height is set to 30 px. You could resize it or `p` will get out `.footer`

Check link : https://jsfiddle.net/L5p38nc3/1/